# golang json array empty result

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

What im doing wrong? I tried tons of way but i get always empty array. Here is my code:

```
type Switches struct {
    switches []SwitchInfo
}

type SwitchInfo struct {
    IP        string
    Community string
}

func main() {
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")

    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", file)

    var jsonObject Switches

    err := json.Unmarshal(file, &jsonObject)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", jsonObject)

}
```

And this is my json file

```
{"switches":
[
    {
    "IP" : "1.1.1.1",
    "Community" : "asdfg"
    },
    {
    "IP" :"1.1.1.1",
    "Community" : "asdf"
    }
]
}
```

I checked my json file it is valid. I think i have problem with my structs. Ty for your help.

Comment: Has been asked a million times. You have to export the fields of the struct you're marshalling into.

Comment: omg! ty sir that mistake take my time horribly. I examined other questions about this but i thougth i was doing everything right sorry for my inattention